# Shopware: cancel the addition of product to the cart conditionally

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I'd like to implement a feature that makes an external API call then depending on whether the request is fulfilled the product line-item gets added to the cart else it shows a translated flash message to the customer that the product couldn't be added to the cart for X reason/s.

What I have tried is subscribing to the `BeforeLineItemAddedEvent` but it seems that the line item is already added to the cart by this point and I'm not quite sure how to implement the flash message thing.

Answer (score 8):

You can implement your own custom cart validator. If your validation criteria is based on a request to an external resource, be mindful that this validator will be called every time the cart gets built. Maybe consider caching those requests.

Service definition:

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\Checkout\Cart\LineItem\CustomValidator">
    <tag name="shopware.cart.validator"/>
</service>
```

Validator class:

```php
class CustomValidator implements CartValidatorInterface
{
    public function validate(Cart $cart, ErrorCollection $errors, SalesChannelContext $context): void
    {
        foreach ($cart->getLineItems()->getFlat() as $lineItem) {
            // your custom logic here
            if ($lineItem->getLabel() === 'Aerodynamic Concrete Isoswitch') {
                $errors->add(new IncompleteLineItemError($lineItem->getId(), 'yourCustomSnippet'));
                $cart->getLineItems()->removeElement($lineItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to implement your own custom extension of `Error` instead using the pre-existing `IncompleteLineItemError` here.

Your translated messages json:

```json
{
  // storefront.en-GB.json
  "checkout": {
    "yourCustomSnippet": "This is not allowed"
  }
}
```

You can find a more detailed explanation in the [docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-validator).

Comment: is there a more generic solution where I can add the validation on the line-items level and not the cart level? since this validator's loop will run each time an item is added

Comment: You could use the payload of the line items to store a flag once you validated them to skip them in upcoming iterations: `$lineItem->setPayloadValue('validated', true);`  Only newly added line items would then miss that payload value: `$lineItem->getPayloadValue('validated') === null`

Comment: I actually did the same exact thing but still would be better to have a non iterative solution

Comment: @dneustadt How would that be done within an app? I guess with App Scripting which is described here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/cart-manipulation. But what if I want to also use the cart manipulation in a Shopware 6.4 instance? Sadly there is no "cart" webhook.